# MS Query executes stored procedure but not returning text

Tags: sql, excel, stored-procedures, ms-query, vba

I am executing a stored procedure via MS query to and Macro Enabled Spreadsheet.

When I I execute it it returns data except for my two description fields.

[image]

When I execute the stored procedure in SQL Server, it executes correctly:

```
    LEFT('All hospitality goods, equipment, and or items described in the Rental Agreement to the debtor supplied from time to time by Silver Chef Rentals Limited - ' + Cast(ad.SerialNumber as varchar) + ' - ' + ad.AssetDescription,199) AS CollateralItemDescription
, 'All hospitality goods, equipment, and or items described in the Rental Agreement to the debtor supplied from time to time by Silver Chef Rentals Limited - ' + CAST(ad.AssetTag as varchar) + ' - ' + ad.AssetDescription as CollateralItemLongDescription
, LEN ('All hospitality goods, equipment, and or items described in the Rental Agreement to the debtor supplied from time to time by Silver Chef Rentals Limited - ' + STUFF((SELECT ', ' + ad2.SerialNumber + ' - ' + ad2.AssetDescription FROM AssetDescription ad2 WHERE rf.ContractNo = ad2.ContractId FOR XML PATH(''), type).value('.', 'nvarchar(max)'),1,1,'')) AS LongDescriptionCount
```

Is there some sort of character limit or do I need to convert?

It seems odd to me.

Comment: hi which fields?

Comment: CollateralItemDescription and CollateralItemLongDescription

Comment: reckon would be a data type mismatch in excel, first start with the length of varchar.. i.e. varchar(max) or varchar(100)